# ¿Error al mostrar propiedad de una colección en vista laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo la siguiente consulta en laravel con query builder:

```
 $datos = $request->input("select");

    $precio = $request->input("Precio");

    $estudios =$request->input('CheckEstudio');

    $conte = count($estudios);



            foreach ($estudios as $key) {
                $sql2[]=DB::table('actividades')
                ->join('proyectos','actividades.id_actividad','proyectos.id_actividad')
                ->select('nombre_actividad')
                ->where('proyectos.id_estudio',$key)->get();


            }
```

la variable $estudios del foreach, me cuenta unos checkbox seleccionados que tengo en la vista, los cuales tienen un valor del 1 al 4, por lo  tanto la variable de la consulta $sql2[] esta declarada como un array, ya que dependiendo el checkbox que seleccionen, la consulta cambia y el resultado se va guardando en el arreglo.

al hacer un dd($sql2); me da el siguiente resultado:

```
 array:4 [▼
  0 => Collection {#184 ▼
    #items: array:11 [▼
      0 => {#188 ▼
        +"nombre_actividad": "2 MODELADO DEL SISTEMA"
      }
      1 => {#183 ▼
        +"nombre_actividad": "ANÁLISIS FLUJO DE CARGA"
      }
      2 => {#185 ▼
        +"nombre_actividad": "ANÁLISIS DE CORTO CIRCUITO "
      }
      3 => {#181 ▼
        +"nombre_actividad": "ANÁLISIS DE PÉRDIDAS DEL SISTEMA "
      }
      4 => {#189 ▶}
      5 => {#186 ▶}
      6 => {#187 ▶}
      7 => {#190 ▶}
      8 => {#191 ▶}
      9 => {#192 ▶}
      10 => {#193 ▶}
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#198 ▶}
  2 => Collection {#209 ▶}
  3 => Collection {#216 ▶}
]
```

La consulta se hace correctamente y se guarda de esa manera, mi problema viene es cuando le envio la variable sql2 a la vista y trato de acceder a la propiedad nombre_actividad para mostrar esos datos en la vista.

```
    return view('actividades',compact('datos','count','consultaActividades','sql2','precio'));
    // dd($sql2) ;







    }

}
```

Asi trato de mostrar los datos:

```
@foreach($sql2 as $sql)
        <tr>
        <td>{{ $sql->nombre_actividad }}</td>

        {{-- @php
        for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 

         echo '<td><input type="text" name"txt[]" value="'.$precio.'"></td>';
        }

        @endphp --}}

                <fieldset id="fieldt"></fieldset>

            </tr>

        @endforeach
```

Este es el mensaje de error que recibo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que puede estar mal?

Comment: no es un json , es un array tienes que tratarlo como tal para recorrerlo.

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, trata de copiar y pegar el código y no una captura del mismo.

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: ¿Como lo recorreria en la vista?

Comment: ya edite la pregunta con el codigo.

Comment: edita tu pregunta plz , pon codigo para ayudarte y trata de pegar el dd que hiciste en formato texto para trabajar sobre el, te ayudará a que te ayudemos.

Comment: Listo, editado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que iterar a través de los elementos de cada colección, o en otras palabras, hacer una doble iteración, teniendo en cuenta la estructura entregada por la consulta:

```
@foreach($sql2 as $sql)

    @foreach($sql as $actividad)

    <tr>
    <td>{{ $actividad->nombre_actividad }}</td>
    ....

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: Excelente me funciono muchas gracias, ya llevaba horas en esto.